# HTML inline element new line text wrapping (for chart legend)

Tags: html, css

I have a chart legend with the below HTML. However, if the text is to long it goes on to a new line under the color square. I need the newline of text to start under the beginning of the text, not under the color square, e.g.
like this:

```
[] lorem ipsum
   lorem ipsum
[] lorem
```

not like this:

```
[] lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
[] lorem
```

This is a minimal example of the HTML I am using. I have tried using `display: flex;` to achieve this (see commented out css) but it squishes the color squares. I need the color square to stay 10px x 10px.

```css
.legend-key {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 20%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
}

#container div {
  /* display: flex; */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <span class="legend-key" style="background-color: red;"></span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="legend-key" style="background-color: green;"></span>
    <span>Facilisis</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="legend-key" style="background-color: blue;"></span>
    <span>Mauris elit enim, elementum scelerisque interdum vehicula</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are after? Just give your legend-key's `flex: 0 0 10px`, that means the element shall neither grow or shrink in size.

you could also write:

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: 10px; //basis of this element is 10px, meaning it takes 10px in size.
```

```css
.legend-key {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 20%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
}

#container div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <span class="legend-key" style="background-color: red;"></span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="legend-key" style="background-color: green;"></span>
    <span>Facilisis</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="legend-key" style="background-color: blue;"></span>
    <span>Mauris elit enim, elementum scelerisque interdum vehicula</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this worked! except now the color square and text are not horizontally aligned. I tried using `align-items: flex-start;` but this didn't help.

Comment: i added margin-top to the legend-key. is this more what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the structure of your markup, that is not the right way to use the flexbox layout. Here are my suggestions and improvements of how I would change it:

1. It is better to use class as a container.
2. Wrap the child elements inside this container.
3. The container should display as display: flex; and by default the child elements will display as rows. You can change the direction by using flex-direction: column to display as column.
4. You can set the width for container of each child as you want it to be.

Hope these would help :)